# Como pegar o CommandText de um IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Estou tentando pegar o `sql` gerado pelo `IQueryable`, mas está retornando:

```
SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
```

Eu esperava algo como:

```
SELECT i FROM lista WHERE i > 20;
```

Como eu estou fazendo:

```
IDbConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=;database=teste");
DataContext db = new DataContext(conn);

List<int> lista = new List<int>();
lista.AddRange(new int[] { 10, 25, 50, 35, 16, 100, 30, 22, 5 });

var query = from i in lista where i > 20 select i;
var dc = db.GetCommand(query.AsQueryable());

Console.WriteLine("Command Text: \n{0}", dc.CommandText);
```

Tem alguma outra maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: o que é o "i" ?

Comment: e outra pergunta, porque estás a criar uma conexao a base de dados, se depois queres aceder ao conteudo da lista?

Comment: @sir_ask Porque é a única forma que achei de conseguir o código sql.

Answer (score 1):

Existe [aqui](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/07/getting-the-sql-query-from-an-entity-framework-iqueryable/) um exemplo que pode ajudar ou mesmo resolver o seu problema:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;

namespace Fenton.Example
{
    public static class IQueryableExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// For an Entity Framework IQueryable, returns the SQL with inlined Parameters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="query"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ToTraceQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
        {
            ObjectQuery<T> objectQuery = GetQueryFromQueryable(query);

            var result = objectQuery.ToTraceString();
            foreach (var parameter in objectQuery.Parameters)
            {
                var name = "@" + parameter.Name;
                var value = "'" + parameter.Value.ToString() + "'";
                result = result.Replace(name, value);
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// For an Entity Framework IQueryable, returns the SQL and Parameters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="query"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ToTraceString<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
        {
            ObjectQuery<T> objectQuery = GetQueryFromQueryable(query);

            var traceString = new StringBuilder();

            traceString.AppendLine(objectQuery.ToTraceString());
            traceString.AppendLine();

            foreach (var parameter in objectQuery.Parameters)
            {
                traceString.AppendLine(parameter.Name + " [" + parameter.ParameterType.FullName + "] = " + parameter.Value);
            }

            return traceString.ToString();
        }

        private static System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T> GetQueryFromQueryable<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
        {
            var internalQueryField = query.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => f.Name.Equals("_internalQuery")).FirstOrDefault();
            var internalQuery = internalQueryField.GetValue(query);
            var objectQueryField = internalQuery.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => f.Name.Equals("_objectQuery")).FirstOrDefault();
            return objectQueryField.GetValue(internalQuery) as System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dá com esse método pegar os parâmetros como uma lista, e usar uma query direto no banco evitando usar uma lista